# Check length of an array and check if HashMap key is in the HashMap (Java, Arrays, HashMaps)

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling, hashmap, logic

I'm trying to do some error trapping.

The error should check if the length of the array is less than 2 and check if the HashMap contains a key that the user has typed in.

The trapped error must use if statements only and must use the .length() method  and must use the .get() method from the HashMap java API.

I have declared the HashMap like so:

```
 private HashMap <String, Shape> shapes;
```

Below is the rest of my code.

```
        String basicCommand = commands[0];
        String moreCommands = commands[1];

    int size = commands.length;

    if(size < 2 && shapes.get(commands[1]).equals(commands[0])){

        if(basicCommand.equals("circle")) {
            makeACircle(commands);
        }
        else if(basicCommand.equals("help")) {
            printHelp();
        }
        else if(moreCommands.equals("left")){
            moveLeft(commands);
        }
        else if(moreCommands.equals("down")){
            shapes.get(commands[0]).moveDown();
        }
        else if(moreCommands.equals("up")){
            shapes.get(commands[0]).moveUp();
        }
        else if(moreCommands.equals("right")){
            shapes.get(commands[0]).moveRight();
        }
        else if(moreCommands.equals("visible")){
            shapes.get(commands[0]).makeVisible();
        }
        else if(moreCommands.equals("invisible")){
            shapes.get(commands[0]).makeInvisible();
        }
        else if(commands[0].equals("forget")){
            shapes.remove(commands[1]).makeInvisible();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Unknown command: " + basicCommand);
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the map contain a key by the method

```
shapes.containsKey(yourKey);
```

And the size of elements in the map if this is what you are looking for by the method:

```
shapes.entrySet().size();
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Luciano Almeida. I have posted my solution based on your answer below. It has solved the problem! thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Luciano Almeida. You were right!!

This is how I solved the problem based on your answer.

If any of you guys have any improvements or suggestions that I could make on the code below, just drop a comment. Thanks!

private void execute(String[] commands)
    {

```
    String basicCommand = commands[0];
    String moreCommands = commands[1];

    int size = commands.length;

    if(basicCommand.equals("circle")) {
        makeACircle(commands);
    }
    else if(basicCommand.equals("help")) {
        printHelp();
    }
    else if(shapes.containsKey(commands[0])){
        if(moreCommands.equals("left")){
            shapes.get(commands[0]).moveLeft();
        }
        else if(moreCommands.equals("down")){
            shapes.get(commands[0]).moveDown();
        }
        else if(moreCommands.equals("up")){
            shapes.get(commands[0]).moveUp();
        }
        else if(moreCommands.equals("right")){
            shapes.get(commands[0]).moveRight();
        }
        else if(moreCommands.equals("visible")){
            shapes.get(commands[0]).makeVisible();
        }
        else if(moreCommands.equals("invisible")){
            shapes.get(commands[0]).makeInvisible();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }        
    else if(commands[0].equals("forget")){
        shapes.get(commands[1]).makeInvisible();
        shapes.remove(commands[1]);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Unknown command: " + basicCommand);
    }

}
```